# How can I assign an issue to a milestone automatically using templates?

Tags: gitlab

I am using GitLab issue templates and they work well. For example I have this one in `.gitlab/issue_templates/foo.md`:

```
# What is happening

# Share screenshots

[describe the issue]

/milestone 15
/confidential true
```

When I use it, it shows the headers and it also labels the issue as confidential, as described in the [GitLab quick actions (FREE)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/doc/user/project/quick_actions.md) doc:

| Command | Issue | Merge request | Epic | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `/confidential` | {check-circle} Yes | {dotted-circle} No | {dotted-circle} No | Make confidential. |
| `/label ~label1 ~label2` | {check-circle} Yes | {check-circle} Yes | {check-circle} Yes | Add one or more labels. Label names can also start without a tilde (~), but mixed syntax is not supported. |
| `/milestone %milestone` | {check-circle} Yes | {check-circle} Yes | {dotted-circle} No | Set milestone. |

However, the piece that does not work is the one that should the Milestone "foo" with the ID 15 I refer to.

How can I assign a Milestone with the name "foo" automatically? Shouldn't `/milestone <id>` suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns up it is as easy as defining it as follows:

```
/milestone <name of the milestone>
```

No ID, just the name.

So you can say:

- `/milestone bla`
- `/milestone this is a milestone with spaces` (note no quotes around the name)